# Javascript Prototype object with Inheritance

Tags: javascript

what is different between Object.create(functionname.prototype) vs new Student() constructor call.

```
function Student(name){
    this.name = name;
}
 function UniversityStudent(id){
    this.id= id;
}


// 1st way
UniversityStudent.prototype = Object.create(Student.prototype);
var std = new UniversityStudent(123);
// but I cannot access std.name why ?

// 2nd way
UniversityStudent.prototype = new Student("Lasith Malinga");
var std1 = new UniversityStudent(123);
// When I use std1.name now then it can
```

When I use 1st way then I cannot access Student`s object properties, but I use 2nd way it can, What is difference. I think both way are same... Is it wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't access `std.name` is because you are not doing the `Student` constructor from the `UniversityStudent` constructor.

You do extend Student successfully with this line:

`UniversityStudent.prototype = Object.create(Student.prototype);`

But when you instantiate it you must do `Student.call(this, name)`

Like this

```
function Student(name){
this.name = name;
}
function UniversityStudent(id, name){
  Student.call(this, name);
  this.id= id;
}
```

Take a look at the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Thank You...... :D

Comment: no problem, make sure to checkout the Inheritance and Prototype Chain page on the MDN, it explains a lot of quirks in the prototype model. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain